# zip folders with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, zip

*Have folder which ends with dot and random strings
I need to zip only those which has two letters after dot*

the sample list of folders are:

```
`ls`
```

> 1113.qy       213cqecqe.cm    ADss.BS     ADss.QQ     ADss.po     a123.qqq    aedrvrvr.aa aefqe.11    ghtyeu.nn   qevaevbae
>   ghtyeu.yg ADss.popoqoQWE
>   ADSD.QQ       ADss.as     adad.qqq    aedrvrvr.cm asdu.wc

### below grep cmd perfectly fits my requirement

```
`ls -a | grep -E '\.[A-Za-z]{2}$'`
```

> .asdas.bC 1113.qy 213cqecqe.cm ADSD.QQ ADss.Cc ADss.QQ ADss.as ADss.po
>   aedrvrvr.aa aedrvrvr.cm asdu.wc ghtyeu.nn ghtyeu.yg

### while zipping such folder, I have error on OSX terminal, tried multiple options but got same error "name not matched"

```
zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/.[A-Za-z{2}$]*

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/'\.[A-Za-z{2}$]*'

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/'\.[A-Za-z]{2}$*'

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/".[A-Za-z{2}]$*"

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/".[A-Za-z{2}]$"
```

#### some other cmd, I tried zipped all folders, like

```
zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/*.[A-Za-z{2}$]*
```

Am I missing something, thank you in advance

```
zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/.[A-Za-z{2}$]*

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/'\.[A-Za-z{2}$]*'

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/'\.[A-Za-z]{2}$*'

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/".[A-Za-z{2}]$*"

zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/".[A-Za-z{2}]$"
```

some other cmd, I tried which zipped all folders, like

```
zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test124/*.[A-Za-z{2}$]*
```

### I would expect folders zipped which have . and two characters

> 1113.qy 213cqecqe.cm ADSD.QQ ADss.BS ADss.Cc ADss.QQ ADss.as ADss.po aedrvrvr.aa aedrvrvr.cm asdu.wc ghtyeu.nn ghtyeu.yg

Answer (score 1):

`zip` command does not recognize `regex`. Even if it does, your syntax expands
the filenames within shell, not zip.

The following would work:

```
zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test24/*.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]
```

In order to make use of `regex`, you can also say something like:

```
find ~/test24 -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.[A-Za-z]{2}" -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it worked >>> zip -r ~/Desktop/33.zip ~/test24/*.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]